# Guardar datos dentro de una variable tipo char en c++

Tags: c++, string

Estoy intentado pedir al usuario unos datos de tipo carácter y cuando los quiero guardar en una variable tipo caracter, me marca un error en c++.

fracmentos del codigo:

```
char elementoBuscado[10];
cout<<"Seleccionar Un Elemento";
            cout<<"Escriba el nombre del elemento: ";
            cin<<elementoBuscado; //el error se encuntra aqui

            if (elementoBuscado == litio){
                cout<<"hola";
            } else{
                cout<<"elemento no encontrado";
            }
```

de antemano pido una disculpa si mi pregunta esta mal formulada o es un poco tonta, aun soy nuevo en la programacion.

Answer (score 1):

Hace años que no veo c y c++, pero voy a intentar ayudarte, ya que tienes varios errores.

1. El título hace pensar que tu variable es un solo char, cuando el tipo de tu variable es una array de char's
2. Ocupas 'cin' con flechas a la izquierda, esto se hace con flechas a la derecha (>>). A mí esto siempre me pareció contraintuitivo
3. Dentro del if, tienes litio como variable pero no la declaras nunca. Por otro lado, si litio es la palabra a buscar debes colocarlo entre comillas "litio"
4. Para comparar un array de char debes ocupar strcmp
   Tu código queda así:

```
    cout<<"Escriba el nombre del elemento: ";
    cin>>elementoBuscado; //el error se encuntra aqui

    if (strcmp(elementoBuscado,"litio")==0){
        cout<<"hola";
    } else{
        cout<<"elemento no encontrado";
    }
```

5. En las etiquetas a tu pregunta pones c++ y string, por lo que entiendo que puedes ocupar string. Un string en c++ viene a suplir el array de char, administrando la memoria automaticamente.
   Con string si puedes ocupar el operador igual (==) para comparar cadenas

```
string elementoBuscado;
cout<<"Seleccionar Un Elemento";
cout<<"Escriba el nombre del elemento: ";
cin>>elementoBuscado; //el error se encuntra aqui

if (elementoBuscado == "litio"){
    cout<<"hola";
} else{
    cout<<"elemento no encontrado";
}
```

Comment: En caso de que la variable sea un arreglo de caracteres (`char[]`), sugiero usar [`cin.getline(elementoBuscado, 10)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) ya que el operador `>>` de **cin** puede terminar escribiendo fuera de la memoria. Como en [este ejemplo](https://ideone.com/RVr4xh) donde escribe también en la memoria de la otra variable.